# Can't capture stdout with unittest

Tags: python-3.x, stdout, python-unittest

I have a python3.7 script, which takes a YAML file as input and processes it depending on the instructions within. The YAML file I am using for unit testing looks like this:

```
...
tasks:
  - echo '1'
  - echo '2'
  - echo '3'
  - echo '4'
  - echo '5'
```

The script loops over tasks and then runs each one, using `os.system()` call.

The manual testing indicates, that the output is as expected:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

But I can't make it work in my unit test. Here's how I'm trying to capture the output:

```
from application import application
from io import StringIO
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

class TestApplication(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_application_tasks(self):
        expected = ['1','2','3','4','5']

        with patch('sys.stdout', new=StringIO()) as fakeOutput:
            application.parse_event('some event') # print() is called here within parse_event()
            self.assertEqual(fakeOutput.getvalue().strip().split(), expected)
```

When running `python3 -m unittest discover -s tests`, all I get is `AssertionError: Lists differ: [] != ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']`.

I also tried using `with patch('sys.stdout', new_callable=StringIO) as fakeOutput:` instead, but to no avail.

Another thing I tried was `self.assertEqual(fakeOutput.getvalue(), '1\n2\n3\n4\n5')`, and here what the unittest outputs:

```
AssertionError: '' != '1\n2\n3\n4\n5'
+ 1
+ 2
+ 3
+ 4
+ 5
```

Obviously, the script works and outputs the right result, but `fakeOutput` does not capture it.

Using `patch` as a decorator does not work either:

```
from application import application
from io import StringIO
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

class TestApplication(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('sys.stdout', new_callable=StringIO)
    def test_application_tasks(self):
        expected = ['1','2','3','4','5']
        application.parse_event('some event') # print() is called here within parse_event()
        self.assertEqual(fakeOutput.getvalue().strip().split(), expected)
```

Would output absolutely the same error: `AssertionError: Lists differ: [] != ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']`

Comment: Your question is incomplete.  Where is the definition of `application`?  A trivial definition with `print("Here is some output")` does not reproduce the behavior you describe.

Comment: Based on the mention of `os.system` though I'll take a guess...

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone yeah, I already realized it... what confused me is that I started using `echo` right away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, Jean-Paul Calderone. I realized the fact, that `os.system()` creates a completely different process and therefore I need to tackle the problem differently, only after I posted the question :)

To actually be able to test my code, I had to rewrite it using `subprocess` instead of `os.system()`. In the end, I went with `subprocess_run_result = subprocess.run(task, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` and then getting the result using `subprocess_run_result.stdout.strip().decode("utf-8")`.

In the tests I just create an instance of class and call a method, which runs the tasks in subprocess.

My whole refactored code and tests are [here in this commit](https://gitlab.com/flexbox/preacher/commit/b6b74c2dd8647c0b5f0ff00c6ce565f3b655317b) if anyone would like to take a look.

Comment: If Jean-Paul's answer helped you, you should just mark it as correct instead of posting your own. Stack Overflow is a wiki. You can actually just edit other people's answers if you have something to add, instead of posting new answers that reference other answers.

Answer (score 1):

`os.system` runs a new process.  If you monkey-patch `sys.stdout` this affects the current process but has no consequences for any new processes.

Consider:

```
import sys

from os import system
from io import BytesIO

capture = sys.stdout = BytesIO()
system("echo Hello")
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
print(capture.getvalue())
```

Nothing is captured because only the child process has written to its stdout.  Nothing has written to the stdout of your Python process.

Generally, avoid `os.system`.  Instead, use the `subprocess` module which will let you capture output from the process that is run.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is fine, just use [`getvalue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO.getvalue) instead, like so:

```
with patch("sys.stdout", new_callable=StringIO) as f:
    print("Foo")
    r = f.getvalue()

print("r: {r!r} ;".format(r=r))
```

> r: "Foo" ;